# Haskell can't call function after '<-'?

Tags: haskell, parse-error

I'm just beginning with Haskell and I can't understand one thing - why doesn't something like this work?

```
fun f = f * f
main = 
    do 
        foo <- getLine 
        bar <- getLine
        print (fun 4)
```

I keep receiving " parse error on input `print' " from ghc. But what's even more mysterious to me is that it works after removing foo <- getLine and bar <- getLine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This means you are mixing tabs and spaces.  Notice white space is important to parsing Haskell.  Your `print` line is probably too far indented (or not indented far enough). Replace all your tabs!

EDIT: Notice a copy/paste of the code you posted will only use spaces and works fine.